# How to disable "Not listed?" on login screen?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3

When I used to use Ubuntu, there was an option on the login screen, which, if you are not in the list of users, allowed you to create a new account. 
Now, looking for same thing in Debian, on the login screen, there is written under my name

" not listed? "

When clicked, it lets you make a new account. I want to disable it.

- Debian Jessie
- Gnome 3

Comment: Are you sure it lets you create a new account? Have you tried that? The screens I know only lets you login as an existing but not listed user such as `root`.

Comment: it lets you create a normal user account not root, but i dont want that too

Comment: No, as already explained by bidifx it doesn't create a new account. Instead you can enter the name of an *existing* user.